# 301 Redirect full path of subdomain to landing page on primary domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am currently trying to redirect a full pathname of a subdomain to a landing page on my WordPress site.

Here is an example of the subdomain I am trying to redirect

`try.example.com/founder`

redirects to

`example.com/founder`

I've tried various methods to accomplish this, and nothing seems to work. I have the domain and cPanel hosting through GoDaddy.

1. I have tried writing in the subdomain in the forwarding section of the DNS records of my primary domain. The issue is that I am unable to write the full path with `/founder` at the end of the subdomain. So the only subdomain I can create for the redirect is `try.example.com`
2. I have created an A record for the subdomain `try` in the DNS, pointing to the IP address of my server. In my cPanel subdomains page, I have created the subdomain `try.example.com`. That subdomain is in the root folder `/public_html/try.example.com`. Inside of the root folder, I have edited the `.htaccess` file to have a redirect script that handles the specific URL I am trying to redirect, which is `try.example.com/founder`.

Here is how the `.htaccess` file looks:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^try\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^founder/?$ https://example.com/our-founder [R=301,L]
```

Now, I have made sure not to have multiple redirect methods happening at the same time. So the only method I currently am using to redirect is the second method I had listed. It still is not redirecting the subdomain path to the landing page URL.

Comment: It's just a type-o in my post here.

Comment: Why include the ``RewriteCond` for the `HTTP_HOST`?  It looks like the way you have it configured, that is the only host name that you expect to have served out of that document root.

Comment: If you put an `index.html` file in that directory, does it get served when you visit `https://try.example.com/`?

Comment: You were right. The .htaccess file I had written was wrong. I had copied and pasted it from somewhere and had just swapped out my website's domain, thinking it was correct. What fixed it was removing the .htaccess file then I went to the Redirect section in the cPanel and wrote in the specific subdomain page that was to be redirected to my landing page, and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the server for the website was really old and was not able to properly manage specific URL redirects. After updating our server I made the following changes, which fixed the issue.

1. Created an A record in the DNS settings with "try" in the name field, and pointing to the server's IP address.
2. Created the subdomain in the cPanel of my server.
3. Updated the .htaccess file in the root directory of my subdomain. In this case it was `try.example.com`. This is how my `.htaccess` file looked:

```js
RewriteEngine on

# Handle the subdomain without the path
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?try\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://example.com/founder [R=301,L]

# Handle the subdomain with the /founder path
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?try\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^founder/?$ https://example.com/founder [R=301,L]
```